# DTO validation in Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a controller with POST method:

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping(value = "/creditDetails", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        @Validated
        public class CreditDetailsController {
       
            @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public CreditDetailsResponse createCreditDetails(@RequestBody @Valid CreditDetailsRequestWithoutId request) {
                return CreditDetailsResponse.convertToResponse(creditDetailsService.createCreditDetails(request));
            }
    }
```

And DTO:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CreditDetailsRequestWithoutId {
    @DecimalMax("10_000_000")
    private BigDecimal creditLimit;
    @DecimalMin("0")
    @DecimalMax("20")
    private BigDecimal creditPercent;
    private UUID bankId;
}
```

When I pass the CreditDetailsWithoutId instance with 111 percent I don't get any errors. Why my validation didn't work?
If it matter i use

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image: no problem]

Comment: For starters start by removing `@Validated` from the controller class. Secondly I wonder if `spring-boot-starter-validation` is the only validator you have or that you proactively added `hibernate-validator` version 7 or higher (or specified a version in the version management).

Comment: @M.Deinum starter is the only validator I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass a decimal value to @DecimalMin, @DecimalMax,:

*@DecimalMax: The value of the field or property must be a decimal value lower than or equal to the number in the value element.* [reference](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/bean-validation002.html)

```
@DecimalMin("0.0")
@DecimalMax("20.0")
private BigDecimal creditPercent;
```

**Later edit:** Removing @Data and adding basic getters & setters fixed the problem on my side, hope it works.

```
// @Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CreditDetailsRequestWithoutId {

    @DecimalMax("1E+7")
    private BigDecimal creditLimit;

    @DecimalMin("0.0")
    @DecimalMax("20.0")
    private BigDecimal creditPercent;

    public BigDecimal getCreditPercent(){
        return creditPercent;
    }

    public void setCreditPercent(BigDecimal creditPercent){
        this.creditPercent = creditPercent;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCreditLimit(){
        return creditLimit;
    }

    public void setCreditLimit(BigDecimal creditLimit){
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: After removing @Data and adding getters and setters it started working on my side, please try again.

Comment: I removed @Data and add getters and setters manually but it still does not work

Comment: Try to also remove **_** from **10_000_000** since that format causes: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character _ is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.` 10000000 = 1E+7

Comment: I still can pass 111 percent even after changing 10000000

Comment: [This](https://ibb.co/0nL5X8t) is how I tested it

Comment: very strange, maybe I have a mistake in the service layer or in the response dto

Answer (score 1):

I've just called `maven clean install` and validation started

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

for my work this:

pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Controller:

```
    @Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthHubController {
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
        public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, @Validated @RequestBody AuthRequestDto authRequestDto) {
    
    }
```

Dto:

```
public class AuthRequestDto {
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{16}", message = "Card number must contain exactly 16 digits")
    String cardNumber; //card number
    }
```

exactly @Validated

Answer (score 0):

You must add EexceptionHandler in your controller class:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;


@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Adding an exception handler wont change a thing.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://github.com/mjimani/springBootValidation)
,This code works for me.

Comment: Again it won't make a difference and in fact it interferes with the default handling that SPring Boot provides. Currently there is no exception being thrown due to no validation being done. No error makes the exception handler pretty useless. Which is also the reason adding it won't make any difference.

Comment: @MohammadJavad i changed @DecimalMax("20.00") to @DecimalMax(value = "20") but nothing changed

Comment: @SmetanaPoAktsii please download this project and run it in your local.
[PLEASE DOWNLOAD](https://github.com/mjimani/springBootValidation)